# Django - Creating a comment system for different pages, using one Comment model

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to create a website with a page for information about different cities. At the bottom of each page, I want there to be a comment section. My idea is to have a Comment model, which stores all the comments in one place, with each comment object having a  field called 'page' which tells me the page they should be displayed on. Then I can just filter through the comments so only the ones for the right page are displayed.

So far I have created a City model which is used by a detail view, CityDetailView, to create a page for each of the cities. This works well and uses a slug for the URLs. I've made a Comment model which accepts: 'content' (describing the city), 'date_posted', 'author' and 'page' which I've connected to the City model through a foreign key. It's my thinking that this 'page' field can be used to store what page the comment was written on, so that I can use `{{ if comments.page == cites.name}}` or something in my city.html template to display the comments only to the correct page.

Going with this thinking, I'm guessing I would need to make a ListView inside the CityDetailView to list the comments. Is this right? I feel there is a better way to do this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevent code, at the moment, no comments show up for the city pages. I have added these manually through the shell, one for each of the two test pages.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from .models import Post, Comment, City, County


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'title':'TIP Home'})   


class CityDetailView(DetailView):
    model = City
    template_name = 'blog/city.html'
    context_object_name = 'cities'

    class CommentsView(ListView):
        model = Comment
        context_object_name = 'comments'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 
from .views import CityDetailView, CountyDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('<slug>/', CityDetailView.as_view(), name='city-detail'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.text import slugify

class City(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    page = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.author)+'-'+str(self.page)+'-'+str(self.pk)        


def slug_generator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.title)

pre_save.connect(slug_generator, sender=City)
```

**city.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="page_heading"><h1>{{ cities.title }}</h1></div>
    <p><center>{{ cities.about }}</center></p>


    {% for comment in comments %}

            <article class="media content-section">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ comment.author }}</a>
                  <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.date_posted|date:'Y n d'  }}</small>
                </div>
                <p class="article-content">{{ comment.content }}</p>
              </div>
            </article>

    {% endfor%}


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I am a little confused. Don't you want to show comments related with the city in your page? Why don't you just use `{% for comment in cities.comment_set.all %}` ?

Comment: Yes I do, so that line makes sense. But how do I link the cities and comments together?

Comment: Django will handle the relation, you can update queryset to add `select_related`. Check the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the get_context_data and through there get access to all the comments for the appropriate page slug.

```
class CityDetailView(DetailView):
    model = City
    template_name = 'blog/city.html'
    context_object_name = 'cities'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.get(page_slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

        return context
```